# How to Put Youtube Video Thumbnail in embed thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, embed

The problem is in the .setThumbnail method. The image is not loaded in the embed. I always get this:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMtiK.png)

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(song.name)
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setThumbnail(song.url); // <- not working
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Comment: Are you using the `googleapis` module to fetch the songs?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `song.url`?

Comment: yes. its a regular youtube link.

Comment: How are you fetching the song data?

Answer (score 0):

Change `.setThumbnail(song.url);` to `.setThumbnail(song.thumbnail);`